# Linking entries with playa

Tags: playa

Basically i have a a channel called "testimonials", this channel has all the testimonial entries.

I have another channel called "franchise" this has all the entires for the franchises.

Basically i want to create a testimonial and with a playa field select what franchise entry this is associated with, and then on the franchise "view" page bring through any testimonials that is related to that entry.

Does anyone know how to do this? or know of another way?

EG:

Testimonial One > Conwy Franchise

Then on the Conwy franchise view page bring through

Testimonial One.

Thanks Wes.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create Playa fields.
2. Add them to franchises. Actually what you illustrated is what you have to do opposite. Instead Testimonial > Franchise, from Franchise Channel entry find playa relation field, which should contain list of testimonials and choose which to to relate with

Few notes: 
This is very simple relation - you can consider using built in EE relation field. If you are on latest EE.2.9 and Playa note they changed the syntax.
!! Consider playa documentation

in template you can visualize relation like so

```
{testimonials}
  {testimonials:author}
  {testimonials:quote}
{/testimonials}
```

This is just an example. *testimonials* is the name of the playa filed.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for reply. No i actually want to do the opposite, I want to be able to publish a testimonial and then decide which franchise it is assosciated with, as opposed to creating loads of testimonials and then going into the franchise entries and pulling them across in the playa field. The reason for this is that i wont be publishing them, someone else will. It is easier for them to create a testimonial as they go along and say to themselves ok this one is for "conwy" this way they dont have to publish the testimonial and then go to the franchise entry and pull it across. Cheers.

Comment: ah - I see - then you definitively need Playa. I noticed about using EE native relation files as you should be careful  with playa as I experienced performance issue on heavy loaded websites

Comment: There will only be limited entries so hopefully it should be ok. But will bare in mind! Do you know how i can do this? Cheers.

Comment: Well I recently edited and converted such relation fields. Regarding what I see [here](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/playa) and what is written [here](http://docs.pixelandtonic.com/playa/using/fields.html) - it should easy like child game :)

Comment: Done, thanks. Sorry should of read the docs as opposed to just submitting a question.

Comment: glad you sorted it out